# How to Add a Style Object to Each Icon in the Array? (React/Material-ui)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material-ui icons, and I would like to add a different icon for each array object shown below. Without manually adding a style property to each object icon in the array, how do I add the "iconStyle" to each object in the array?

```js
import Icon1 from "material-ui/icons"
import Icon2 from "material-ui/icons"

//if i have an array like this:


const array = [
  {name: "test1", icon: <Icon1/>}, //material ui icon1
  {name: "test2", icon: <Icon2/>}, //material ui icon2
]

//and i map through it like this:
const txtStyle = {//css};
const iconStyle = {//css}

<div>
  {array.map(arr => {
    return <div>
      <p style={txtStyle}>{arr.name}</p>
      {arr.icon} // how do i add the iconStyle to this element?
    </div>
  
  })}
</div>

// how do i add the iconStyle object to the person.icon without adding it manually to each icon in the array?

//not like this:

const array = [
  {name: "test1", icon: <Icon1 style={iconStyle}/>}, //material ui icon1
  {name: "test2", icon: <Icon2 style={iconStyle}/>}, //material ui icon2
]
```

Any feedback/help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import Icon1 from "material-ui/icons"
import Icon2 from "material-ui/icons"
import { SvgIcon } from "@material-ui/core"; //import SvgIcon



const array = [
  {name: "test1", icon: Icon1}, //remove tags
  {name: "test2", icon: Icon2},
]


<div>
  {array.map(arr => { //use component and svg icon
    return <div>
      <p style={txtStyle}>{arr.name}</p>
      <SvgIcon component={arr.icon} className="whateverclassyouwant"/> 
    </div>
  
  })}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

there are two ways to do that.

#### Method 1

Make your `icons` accepts the props

```
const arr = [
  { name: "Circle", Icon: (props) => <Icon1 {...props} /> },
  { name: "Shopping", Icon: (props) => <Icon2 {...props} /> }
];
```

Now the style object can be passed as a regular prop to the icons.

```
<div>
    {arr.map((item) => (
        <>
            <p style={txtStyle}>{item.name}</p>
            <item.Icon style={iconStyle}/>
        </>
    ))}
</div>
```

---

#### Method 2

If you're using `makeStyles` to add the styles then you can add a class to the container `div` and then target the icon from that container rule.

```
export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Box>
      {arr1.map((item) => (
        <div className={classes.iconDiv}>
          <p>{item.name}</p>
          {item.icon}
        </div>
      ))}
    </Box>
  );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  iconDiv: {
    "&>p": {
      color: "red"
    },
    "&>svg": {
      color: "green",
      cursor: "pointer"
    }
  }
}));
```

in this method, there's no need to change the `arr` array.

Here is a working example of both methods...
[image: Edit jolly-northcutt-ge4pg]

Answer (score 1):

Just you can take only reference of the icon component then render it in `array.map`

```
const array = [
  {name: "test1", icon: Icon1}, // attention on this line
  {name: "test2", icon: Icon2},
]

const txtStyle = {};
const iconStyle = {};

return (
  <div>
    {array.map(arr => (
      <div>
        <p style={txtStyle}>{arr.name}</p>
        <arr.icon style={iconStyle}/>
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
)
```